# SASL create user failure

Tags: memcached, sasl

I am trying to add new user to SASL db with:

```
 saslpasswd2 -a memcached -c <new_user>.
```

Once I repeat password I get following error:

```
 saslpasswd2: generic failure
```

I was not able to find any solution online...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If anyone has similar problem, solution is to add `sudo` before `saslpasswd2`...

```
sudo saslpasswd2 -a memcached -c <new_user>
```